# Single Jenkins job with multiple deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can we configure a Jenkins job for different environment. We are using a git repository with different branch like master , test  and devl and these environments are deployed in different servers. I have configured build with parameter option, so I can build any of the branch from this job using the radio button. 
When I choose devl branch the job need to take latest code from devl branch and build it then need to deploy into devl server. If we choose test, it will need to deploy into test server. How do we configure this multiple deployment within this same job?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin.
This plugin will watch all your branches of your repo and builds the different  branches based on a Jenkinsfile.

In the Jenkinsfile you can use the `when` expression:

```
   stage('Deploy devl') {
        when {
            expression { env.BRANCH_NAME == 'devl' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'deploy devl'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why did you choose to do it in 1 job, and not different jobs?
2. What tool do you use for deployment?

What I can suggest - not getting too deep inside the details (as I don't have them).

Have a job for each of the different environments, connect each job to the relevant git repository and branch, whenever this job is built, it will perform an scm checkout (you can also trigger it on change using hooks) and deploy to the relevant environment.

If you would answer #2 I may be able to suggest other options to manage this (possibly under the same job - if you require this for some reason).